# Power issues involving Raspberry Pi

Tags: mobile-robot, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi (Model B) attached to a Roomba. I'm using [this part](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1065) to bring the unregulated 17V+ power of the Roomba down the 5V/1A of the Pi. The problem is that the Pi will randomly reboot and cause peripherals (such as the bluetooth adapter) to freak out and not work. We can sometimes drive it around for a little while before it reboots, other times it happens almost immediately.

Comment: 1. What does the Roomba spec on the 17V supply? 2. Did you put a scope on both sides of this (the input and output of your regulator)?

Comment: 3. did you follow the application notes here http://www.tracopower.com/products/tsr1.pdf ?

Comment: I went looking for a source online, and it turns out the battery is 14.4 volts, at lease for a comparable replacement battery. I'm an idiot and after reading these comments I realized I forgot the capacitors. What is L1?

Comment: You should rewrite that comment as an answer to the question so that it can receive upvotes.

Comment: I'm not trying step down more then 32V and I don't need to meet "EN 55022 class A", do I still need those things? I'm getting 5V and 1A out to the Pi.

Comment: @IanHyzy L1 is an inductor.  The second setup provide better filtering but if you get by just by adding one capacitor then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @IanHyzy Does the Raspberry Pi run without rebooting if you use a wall wart when your bluetooth and other peripherals are attached? If your peripherals are drawing a lot of current, you can easily exceed the pi's 750 mA limit (which includes powering itself).

Comment: The Pi runs just fine (with all adapters) even when on computer USB power. Also @GuySirton so one capacitor should be fine?

Comment: @IanHyzy Can't say for sure.  Motors are generally noisy beasts so you would expect the power rails of a working Roomba to be noisy.  Depending on the noise you may need to take more radical measures than the filter cap but it might work.  An oscilloscope on that input power would show you what it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi B, and in particular the Raspberry Pi B2 are fairly sensitive to having enough current to meet their peek power needs. For most of my apps, I have been using a 1.5A supply, and that has been more than sufficient for the Raspberry Pi B+, however when I started trying to use the Raspberry Pi B2 I needed a peak of 3A to be able to not have it "brown out" and reboot.

I would recommend upping your available power, and see if it makes a difference.